How to unsubscribe(disconnect to channel) when using Spring Reactive Redis pub/sub?
I'm currently using Reactive Redis pub/sub in the spring, I'd like to unsubscribe
Do you know how to cancel my subscription if I experience certain situations like socket disconnection when I use ReactiveRedistemplate.listenChannel() or ReactiveReddisMessageListerContainer ?
In the redis pub/sub environment(not reactive redis), I understand that you can cancel the subscription by providing the removeListener of the RedisMessageListenerContainer(RedisMessageListenerContainer.removeListener())
@Service
class RedisMessageSubscriber(
    private val redisTemplate: ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Any>,
    private val reactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer: ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer
) {
    private val log = logger()

    fun subscribe(channel: String, ctx: ChannelHandlerContext) {
        val subscribe = redisTemplate.listenToChannel(channel)
            .map {
                MapperUtils.readJsonValueOrThrow(it.message.toString(), ChatDto::class)
            }
            .subscribe { it ->
                ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(CustomResponse(ResponseType.RECEIVE_CHAT, it))
                    .addListener {
                        if (it.isSuccess) {
                            log.info("write channel topic: $channel")
                        } else {
                            ctx.channel().close()
                            log.warn("Failed to send the message to the client. roomId:${channel}, message:${it.cause()}, socketOpen: ${ctx.channel().isOpen}")
                            throw IllegalArgumentException("socket close")
                        }
                    }
            }
        log.info("isDispose: ${subscribe.isDisposed}")
    }
}

I thought if the socket channel was closed, Redis' subscription would also be cancelled, but it was still there.

Disclaimer: I was not able to find a good example in the documentation on how this is to be handled, but it works for me when I am testing locally.
Since your example shows the use of the ChannelHandlerContext (which I assume is the same as the one used in Netty) then I made the assumption you are using the Lettuce driver.
In this case you could configure your connection factory with a RedisConnectionStateListener to hook with the disconnection event and use the .destroy() or .activeSubscriptions methods of the ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer :

    @Bean
    fun reactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer(
        reactiveRedisConnectionFactory: LettuceConnectionFactory?
    ): ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer {
        val container = ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer(reactiveRedisConnectionFactory!!)
        val connectionListener = object : RedisConnectionStateAdapter() {
            override fun onRedisDisconnected(connection: RedisChannelHandler<*, *>?) {
                container.activeSubscriptions.forEach {
                    val channels =
                        it.channels.stream().map { channel -> String(channel.array()) }.reduce { acc, s -> "$acc, $s" }
                    LOGGER.info("Canceling subscription for ${channels.get()} ")
                    it.cancel().subscribe()
                }
                //or you can use container.destroy() alternatively
            }
        }

        reactiveRedisConnectionFactory.start()
        reactiveRedisConnectionFactory.nativeClient?.addListener(connectionListener)

        return container
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun reactiveRedisConnectionFactory(
    ): LettuceConnectionFactory {
        val redisConfiguration = RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port)
        val lettuceConnectionFactory = LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration)
        return lettuceConnectionFactory
    }


Note: The way the spring-data-redis works in this case is that it purposefully does not unsubscribe from the channels, so that when the connection is re-established it would be able to re-subscribe. I assumed this is not something that the application has to do in this case, but for most cases this would be the correct approach.
